# Is it ok to save large html content in the database when building a CMS

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I'm building a site which mainly has articles and I'm using **ASP.NET MVC 5** framework and SQL server.

I want to handle the site as a Content Management System, where I can add, edit these article content. 
I'm planning to use a **Rich text editor** (TinyMCE) to handle content of an article (Add and edit text, images, links etc.).

In this approach I'll have to save the html of a whole article page in a database column, like given below.

*Article table columns*

- ArticleId
- ArticleTitle
- CreatedDate
- Content (The html of the whole article, generated by the text editor)

I searched about saving html in database and I found mixed responses.
I would want to know is this conceptually  correct in a general perspective and in an ASP MVC perspective. and I'm open to alternative approach.

Comment: Do you have any a templating section of your CMS? A part of your system which allows you to create a set of templates for specific types of pages? E.g. a news article template, a product template, a standard page template?

Comment: @DavidFord Not really.

Comment: It's definitely something you should consider using, that way the concrete pages will reference a template and you only need to store the content of that page and not the entire template and content. I'll write a full answer shorty.

Comment: @DavidFord Can you elaborate this a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching a lot on this,

Lots of CMSs save **HTML content generated from Rich Text Editors** in databases as HTML (Even Wordpress 
[Why does Wordpress stores HTML in the Database](https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/2t5kri/why_does_wordpress_stores_html_in_the_database/)).

So the below approach is pretty acceptable.

Article table columns

- ArticleId
- ArticleTitle
- CreatedDate
- Content (The html content, generated by the text editor)

When rendering the page, use a template for the Article page, which will handle the layout of the page.